# Contornar problema com desenvolvimento a quente em Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee, tomcat, desempenho

Situação problema:

Você está desenvolvendo um site web e fazendo depurações no mesmo. Por exemplo um CRUD de usuários.
Para isso você está usando JavaEE 1.7, Eclipse Kepler e Apache Tomcat 7.
Contudo, ao delongo do desenvolvimento, e já com a aplicação em modo de debug, pode ser que você encontre um erro e decida alterar o código.
Mas para isso, ao alterar o código, o Eclipse reconstroi (rebuild) o código para deixá-lo disponível novamente.
Contudo, neste momento o Tomcat reinicia.
Fazendo isso repetidamente, um bom tempo de desenvolvimento é gasto.

Como contornar este problema?
Há alguma maneira de desenvolver de forma que as alterações novas entrem, mas o servidor permaneça do jeito que estava?

Por exemplo, em PHP, caso aconteça um erro ou alguma exception qualquer, o servidor loga o erro, mas não reinicia. Basta que você altere o arquivo e rode novamente o código que tudo vai estar ok (que chamei de desenvolvimento a quente assim como temos backup a quente).

Há alguma maneira de resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 4):

## *Hot Code Replacement*

A JVM tradicional da Oracle possibilita o *hot code replace* até certo ponto desde a versão 1.4, quando ainda era da Sun.

Se você estivesse conectado em modo de depuração (*debug*) através de uma ferramenta adequada como o [Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace?), então as alterações em classes recompiladas seriam injetadas na JVM enquanto ela ainda estava executando.

Entretanto, há várias limitações: não é possível adicionar ou remover métodos e atributos, alterar assinaturas e coisas desse tipo.

Por outro lado é bem possível criar novas classes, alterar o conteúdo de métodos, injetar valores em variáveis enquanto a execução está pausada, etc.

## Aplicações web

Mas falando especificamente sobre aplicações web, não é apenas isso que importa. Muitas vezes o container é configurado para recarregar quando ele reconhece alguma alteração em determinados arquivos, como o `web.xml`, por exemplo. Alguns plugins das IDEs disparam esse processo automaticamente quando você altera o código para garantir a atualização da aplicação.

Além disso, servidores de aplicação como o Tomcat fazem cache de conteúdo estático, incluindo JSPs, imagens e CSS. O Tomcat 6, por exemplo, vinha configurado para fazer literalmente uma cópia de toda a sua aplicação numa pasta temporária. Isso é bom para produção, mas para desenvolvimento é um pesadelo.

Para ver detalhes sobre essas questões do Tomcat, acesse ,eu artigo [*Evite reiniciar o Tomcat 6 e deixe a inicialização mais rápida*](http://luizricardo.org/2012/09/evite-reiniciar-o-tomcat-6-e-deixe-a-inicializacao-mais-rapida/). Provavelmente não é muito diferente do Tomcat 7.

## Java vs. Linguagens Dinâmicas

De certa forma, ao comparar o "*deploy*" de arquivos PHP com Java, é comparar bananas com laranjas.

Em PHP, a simples cópia de arquivos é suficiente porque na maioria dos casos porque ele não armazena estado e interpretada os arquivos a cada requisição. Mas pense no custo disso em relação ao desempenho do sistema.

O grande benefício de Java na escalabilidade é justamente um arquitetura que persiste objetos em memória e os reutiliza eficientemente. O estado do sistema permanece o mesmo a cada requisição e assim o desempenho geral é muito maior.

Sobre a questão de disponibilidade para o usuário, embora em geral seja necessário fazer o *redeploy* da aplicação, isso pode ser remediado com o uso de *clusters* e a atualização parcial dos mesmos até que todos os nós recebam as atualizações.

## A arquitetura da sua aplicação importa

Alguns frameworks funcionam melhor do que outros. Dependendo do tipo de alteração que você está fazendo, ele pode ajudar ou atrapalhar a testar alterações.

Um detalhe muito comum em aplicações grandes é carregar arquivos `.properties` de internacionalização (I18n). O problema é que os *bundles* não são recarregados se alterados, pelo menos não por padrão. Só que alguns frameworks como struts2 ou Spring permitem você configurá-los para recarregar os arquivos com os textos traduzidos sem reiniciar a aplicação.

Aliás, muitos frameworks possuem um modo de desenvolvimento. Por exemplo, o PrimeFaces em modo "dev" exibe muitos detalhes sobre os erros ocorridos e o contexto do *facelet* no momento da exceção, incluindo as variáveis que estavam nos escopos de requisição e sessão.

Tire vantagem disso para evitar corrigir os problemas na "tentativa e erro" e ir direto ao problema. É importante entender os mecanismos do seu framework para obter a melhor produtividade.

## Produtividade na prática

Com o conhecimento de detalhes sobre a IDE, o servidor de aplicação e o framework utilizado, você pode realizar ajustes finos em seu ambiente de desenvolvimento e alcançar uma produtividade muito maior, embora ainda tenha que arcar com a reinicialização do servidor quando fizer alterações estruturais em suas classes.

Embora as ferramentas possam ajudar, e muita gente concorda que o JRebel ajuda, a melhor forma de melhorar a produtividade é através da mudança de abordagem dos desenvolvedores. Por experiência própria eu digo que às vezes ficamos testando diversas possíveis solução como tentando solucionar um labirinto pela força bruta. Ao invés de focar na facilidade de atualização para ficar testando várias possibilidades, pense primeiro com mais cuidado sobre como o problema deve ser resolvido. Isso diminuirá muito o número de vezes que você precisa "corrigir e testar" a aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

Existe um produto chamado JRebel que possibilita ao Tomcat trabalhar em modo de deployment contínuo:

> http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Ele é proprietário, mas possui uma versão trial. O suporte é bastante atencioso. Quando testei o produto, chegaram a me ligar e me pedir um feedback do produto.